# Node.js: Adding SVG to a specific page of PDF by pdfmake

Tags: node.js, svg, pdfmake, node-pdfkit

I am trying to create PDF content by [pdfmake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake). However, pdfmake do not support adding SVG at v0.1.38.
So I use [SVG-to-PDFKit](https://github.com/alafr/SVG-to-PDFKit/blob/master/source.js) to achieve that. Here is my code:

```
var printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fontDescriptors);

var doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfDoc);

SVGtoPDF(doc, s.data, s.x, s.y, s.options); // add this line for SVG-to-PDFKit to insert SVG while s contain SVG data

var chunks = [];
var result;

doc.on('data', function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
});
doc.on('end', function() {
    result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    resolve(result);
});
doc.end();
```

SVG is successfully added to the last page. How to add the SVG to a specific page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the source code and [document](https://pdfkit.org/docs/guide.pdf), adding `{ bufferPages: true }` fix your need perfectly.

```
var printer = new pdfMakePrinter(fontDescriptors);

var doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfDoc, { bufferPages: true }); // magic here!
doc.switchToPage(x); // to page x, where x start from 0

SVGtoPDF(doc, s.data, s.x, s.y, s.options); // add this line for SVG-to-PDFKit to insert SVG while s contain SVG data

var chunks = [];
var result;

doc.on('data', function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
});
doc.on('end', function() {
    result = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    resolve(result);
});
doc.end();
```

Comment: awesome, perfect answer!